# Laravel 11 foreign key not showing up in SQL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-11

What steps should I follow to correctly set up two foreign keys in Laravel 11, as I've been having difficulties with this task?

```php
$table->id();

$table->foreignId('news_id')
      ->constrained(table: 'news')
      ->cascadeOnDelete()
      ->cascadeOnUpdate();

$table->foreignId('category_id')
      ->constrained(table: 'categories')
      ->cascadeOnDelete()
      ->cascadeOnUpdate();

$table->timestamps();
```

[image: Image of my db designer]

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what isn't working? are you getting an error? what is actually happening?

Comment: that looks like phpmyadmin. It's notoriously bad at showing relevant information. Check if the constraitns appear in the table > constraints view. Also, have you actually run this migration?

Comment: Make sure both of the tables have the InnoDB engine selected.

Comment: It worked by using innoDB thanks